# Proving $r(t) \cdot r'(t) = 0$ for a vector valued function

Tags: calculus, vectors

A theorem in my calculus textbook states that if $r(t$) is a differentialable vector-valued fuction of $t$, and $c$ is a scalar, then:

If:
$$r(t) \cdot r(t) = c $$ 
Then: 
$$ r(t) \cdot r'(t) = 0$$

I have been trying to understand why this is true but can't think of any way to understand it analytically or graphically.

Comment: Your calculus textbook should have the product rule for dot product, $\frac{d}{dt}\bigl( r(t) \cdot s(t) \bigr)= \frac{d}{dt}(r(t)) \cdot s(t) + r(t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt}(s(t))$. Apply that to the equation $r(t) \cdot r(t) = 0$ by taking $\frac{d}{dt}$ of both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two dimensions, it tells you that the tangent to a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$  at some point is orthogonal to the vector from the origin to that point. Graphically that should make sense.

Using,

$$\vec r \cdot \vec r=c$$

Differentiating both sides gives the desired result.

$$2 \vec r \cdot \vec r'=0$$

$$\vec r \cdot \vec r'=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d}{dt}(r \cdot r)= r \cdot r' + r \cdot r' = 2 r \cdot r' = \frac{d}{dt}(c) = 0$$

Hence $r \cdot r' = 0$.